# Pass from yearbirth to age in r

Tags: r

I have of this years of birth on my data and i want to convert to the age of this differents persons in 2017. How can I do?

```
table(d$age)

1928 1929 1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 
 175  155  134  133  199  215  237  278  325  350  433  479  574  532  549  527  560  644  707 
1947 1948 1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 
 816  811  812  926  850  856  880  840  921  879  879  879  822  932  838  904  869  936  903 
1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 
 880  802  843  875  871  786  795  803  742  759  719  746  778  788  808  694  731  691  663 
1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 
 653  683  613  673  618  634  576  640  532  509  528  550  533  507  541  604  471  504  350 
2004 
  45
```

Comment: `2017 - d$age`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not hard to do:

If your year of brith data are numeric:

```
yob <- c(1955, 2000, 1900)
age <- 2021 - yob
age
[1]  66  21 121
```

If they are character:

```
yob <- c("1955", "2000", "1900")
age <- 2021 - as.numeric(yob)
```